# Go to a specific place in a word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I wrote the following script which enable me to open a word doc from outlook:

```
Sub OpenSOPRR()
    Dim wordApp As Word.Application
    Dim wordDoc As Word.Document

    Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If wordApp Is Nothing Then
        Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        wordApp.Visible = True
    End If
    Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\aa471714\Desktop\Doc1.doc")
    Set wordApp = Nothing
    Set wordDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

I now however would like to add something which enable me to directly go to a particular place in the doc. So that i for example classify a header on page 2 as "area1" and can directly go there...

Comment: Usually this would be done with bookmarks, which can then be navigated to using GoTo. Are you able to add bookmarks to the document that the script could then interact with?

Comment: you need to tell us exactly what you want to find in your document to get any idea from us. @Christina's idea is one of the most popular technique. But there could be some more as far as some part of document are explicitly separated. The other popular solution is to use `.find` object to get to appropriate part of document. Try with macro recorder.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions guys. Solved it. Just had to add a bookmark to my worddoc with for example "appels" and then add the following code:

Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="Oranje"